# Replace values from another table without merging Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, pq

I would like to replace values in a columns from corresponding values in another table avoiding merging and expanding columns.

Data which I want to send to another table:
[image]

Table where I want to replace data:
[image]

As you can see I have 2 tables but they have different formatting, plus this 1st table (OQC) have some the same columns as 2nd table (result)

So I would like to replace this data from 2nd table by this data from 1st table.

Comment: why do you not want to merge?

Comment: Its 2 reports of some automotive parts. This table (OQC) is report after verify some of the parts in column result we have 2 options OK/NG some of this parts after verify was bad or good and this need change status e.g OK to NG with rest of the columns like "type of defect" and so on.

Comment: It is unclear what columns you want to put where, or why you want to avoid major functions like merge. Please provide a sample of before/after data

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/eMjMznr.png

Comment: Agree, this is a textbook merge. You merge based on your common ID (LOT ID), expand the new col, delete the old col, rename the new col if needed. done. BTW, I noticed you duplicate your function, you should parametrize it instead.

Comment: I have already done it, it turned out that I did not know about the existence of the option to merge the query haha